# Django and angular6 with multitenancy

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie to Multi-Tenant architecture, developing SaaS product using django-tenant-schema

my requirement was something like clients would register for product. For every registered client, I was creating new schema by following single database and isolated schemas approach. Whenever client requested from a browser I was able to identify them by using subdomain and giving privilege to acces their specfic schema. While I was starting coding lot of questions were popup in my head. I am really sorry for asking here but stackoverflow is only my last hope. Database was like below

Database
Public_Schema
auth_user
Clients_List_Table
ClientA_Schema
auth_user
ClientA_User_List
ClientB_Schema
auth_user
ClientB_User_List
Q1.What kind of admin actions we can perform on every client?

I have rest api for example http://client.example.com/api/user_list/ here client maybe ClientA or ClientB

Q2. How can we implement api routing which gets client name dynamically when user requested at browser which let us to use corresponding schema to display current client's user_list.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! Yes it is possible to use both angular and django to build restful api application. Anyway, this question is to broad to answer and you should narrow it down to more specific so user here won't have any trouble helping you.

Comment: Please narrow your question to as narrow as it can be.
The answer is Yes, but I don't think you are searching for a 'YES' here in StackOverflow. Please share what problem are you facing while implementing the approach.

Comment: I want to create a multitenant rest API like http://example.com/api/login and need to route it this page  http://client1.example.com/api/employee using Django tenant schema then I need to connect to this multitenant Django backend with angular 6 is it possible ?